# Remote kernel works in terminal but not in Notebook

Tags: front-end, kernel, remote-access, kernel-startup

I am using a Mac OS 12.2.1 computer that's trying to connect to a remote kernel in a Windows 10 computer. I am able to connect to that computer via ssh in terminal. Inside the terminal, I can launch a Mathematica kernel with "wolfram" command, which works just fine.
However, I am now trying to let the notebook frontend use this remote kernel. Using the same settings in the "basic" settings of kernel configuration, Mathematica asks for my password, then pauses for a while, before displaying "cannot connect to kernel, errorcode=MLE connect".
Trying the same command with `LaunchKernels` as following:

```
LaunchKernels[
 RemoteKernelObject["ssh://username@ipaddress", 
  "KernelCommand" -> 
   "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Wolfram Engine\\12.3\\math", 
  "KernelCount" -> 1]]
```

Results in
[image]

Which I cannot comprehend. I tried reinstalling Mathematica on both my computer and on the remote computer, but nothing worked. My friend could connect to the remote kernel with the same command on a Windows 10 laptop, so what happened?

Comment: Have you contacted Wolfram [support](https://support.wolfram.com/) about it? It works from the command line and you mentioned that the same command works on a Windows10 laptop, so it is likely that the support might have an answer ready for this scenario.

Comment: Seems related to character encoding?